# Подскажите в чем синтаксическая ошибка?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код, на котором браузер выдает ошибку (LINE 221):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO active (
    inv_n, name_act, id_cat, ed_izm, quantity, price, id_dep, comments, id_stat) 
VALUES (
    '".$inv_n."','".$name_act."','".$id_cat"','".$ed_izm"','".$quantity"',
    '".$price"','".$ed_dep"','".$comments"','".$id_stat"');";
```

Сама ошибка выглядит вот так:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"','"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\uchet\active.php on line 221

Comment: Не нужно делать программирование сложным) Ну непонятно же нифига, не говоря о инъекцияъ. Перепишите на `INSERT INTO a (x, y) VALUES (?, ?)`

Comment: В конкатенации строк.

Comment: У меня точно такая же ошибка: https://3v4l.org/aSsCQ Значит, с вашим php всё в порядке

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO active ( inv_n, name_act, id_cat, ed_izm, quantity, price, id_dep, comments, id_stat) VALUES ( '".$inv_n."','".$name_act."','".$id_cat."','".$ed_izm."','".$quantity."','".$price."','".$ed_dep."','".$comments."','".$id_stat."');";

Answer (score 0):

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(`id`,`name`) VALUES('$id','$name')";

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]